# View passwords of all Wi-Fi networks my Mac has connected to in the past

Tags: macos, terminal, wifi, password

I have connected my Mac to lots of public Wi-Fi networks. I want to know their passwords. What should be the **terminal command** to list all the Wi-Fi networks whom I connected with in the past with their passwords.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Open **Keychain Access** from /Applications/Utilities and search for **AirPort**. All the network passwords are listed as 'AirPort network password' entries. Double-click an entry, then select **Show Password** and enter your login password to view it.

Comment: thanks thats the graphical way, found other way to do it via terminal: cd /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport

Comment: → Stack: could you develop the method you found, and make an answer of it?

Comment: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport is an executable file in current version of MacOS.  'cd' to it is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Keychain Access app. It is located in the Applications > 
   Utilities folder.
2. Select the System keychain in the left menu bar, and select 
   Passwords from the category menu. This will filter the keychains to 
   just your stored passwords

[image]
[image]
  PFA below.

---