# How to find wifi passwords in Yosemite or iOS8

Tags: macos, network, wifi, password, keychain

I can still connect to this foreign network using this new computer -- my old computer had access. I want to share the password with my wife's system.

I can't figure out how to do this, either in Yosemite or iOS8.

I've looked at [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150297/view-passwords-of-all-wi-fi-networks-my-mac-has-connected-to-in-the-past) among others. Keychain Access doesn't seem to hold wifi passwords any longer. (I've used this method in the past).

Has anyone else seen this? Am I looking incorrectly or is there a new location/method?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keychain Access still stores the passwords:

Go to Applications > Utilities and open the Keychain Access app. On the left side field, click "System," and in the left field "Category" click "Passwords". From here, you can double-click on each network in the "Name" column, and click the "Show password" box to show the network password. You may have to enter your Mac's Username/Password to view each Network Password.

I'm not aware of any way to do this direct from iOS 8, but your iOS passwords will be stored here as well. If you don't see them, on your iOS device, go to Settings > iCloud > Keychain, and turn on "iCloud Keychain" if it isn't already. Apple may text you a security code to verify this: Enter the code on your iOS device. Your saved Wi-Fi passwords should show up shortly, but you may have to close and re-open Keychain Access.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I was looking in "login" rather than System.

Answer (score 2):

You can see **saved passwords** on **iOS8** by going to:

*Settings->Safari->Passwords & Autofill->Saved Passwords*.

You then need to enter you passcode.

Scroll to the entry of interest and select it.

This will show you the **Username** and **Password**.

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't exactly what I was asking, but it's helpful information nonetheless.